# Catching errors in JS via eventListeners

Tags: javascript, error-handling, dom-events

Is there a way to handle errors like `ReferenceError` or `TypeErro`r in JS using event Listeners ? I know of try .. catch.. but that is not what I am looking for.

For example : I am looking for a method like `document.onReferenceError` or similar event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to do global error handling.  For errors you can't really tap into a *type* per se, but you can listen for all errors using:

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) { ... }
```

For element specific errors you have a different function signature ("for historical reasons" - per docs)

```
element.onerror = function(event) { ... }
```

In either case you should be able to inspect the `error` or the `event` for a type of `instanceof` check.

```
//in case of global level checking
error instanceof ReferenceError //boolean

//in case of element level checking
event.type === <type you're looking for>  //boolean
```

docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Comment: Takes me somewhat closer to solving the problem